# How to take screenshots of multiple screens for the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am curious about what is the best way to take screenshots of my game for the App Store.

The App Store requires screenshots for every device, however I don't really know how this can be achieved. Let's say I run my game first in the iPhone 6 simulator, take some screenshots while playing the game, then switch to the iPhone 6 Plus simulator and play the game again. How can I take the same screenshots? Especially if the game is randomly generating terrain for the levels. The terrain won't be the same as it was on the iPhone 6 simulator.

I know I could give the screenshots a frame, and resize the frame only in photoshop while having the same screenshot for all devices. But what if I wan't to take screenshots only of the game (no frame, what so ever)? How do developers overcome this?

Comment: They don't have to be the exact same screenshot in a different size, I would just try to show a similar situation (it can be as general as just "gameplay").

Comment: Try this: https://launchkit.io/screenshots/  I've used it and recommend it.

Comment: fastlane utilize UI testing framework to capture screenshots and use assets from Apple to add frames: https://fastlane.tools/